# Why np.ones creates a black image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to understand what is the difference between `np.zeros`and `np.ones`. In my bellow code both create a black images. But what is the use of `np.zeros`and `np.ones`. When should i use them. What is the purpose. I know `np.ones` fill matrix with 1 but what is the purpose. What i want to create a `white image`

```
img = np.ones((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('IMG', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('IMG', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what further answer you could expect other than "an ndarray full of zero values" or "an ndarray full of one values". In terms of RGB I doubt you'd actually see anything different.

Comment: white is 255 for type `uint8`

Comment: what is the color of `ones` and `zeros`

Comment: ``both create a black images`` - Nope, one creates a black image, the other one a dark grey, where all pixels are ``rgb(1, 1, 1)``.

Comment: so, in OpenCV with uint8 the difference is just a shade of black (0 or 1) if it is with float, it is black or white, since OpneCV uses 0-1 values when it is float

Comment: From its name you can see that one is creating the array fills with 1 and the other fills the array with 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.zeros` "Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with zeros."

`np.ones` "Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with ones."

```
np.zeros(10)
Out: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
np.ones(10)
Out:array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: What, 3 upvotes for what's in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-creation.html)?

Comment: @roganjosh Well yes? It's what the question asked for ... oO

Comment: @meissner_ It was not. The real question was just hidden in this sentence: 'What i want to create a white image'

Comment: @meissner_ except that it isn't. From context we can see that they are confused about RGB

Comment: Many coders are lacking this basic skills: documentation use, research, finding information. hence why I believe the upvotes. "What is the purpose." suggests author of the question does not understand what np.ones and what np.zeros do and what an array is as he does not understand what np.ones((512,512,3)) does.

Comment: @meissner_ I am really new to opencv topic. I was understanding if we are giving` np.zeros` then it should create black image and if `np.ones` then it should create white image –

Comment: @HuzaifSayyed which is why this doesn't answer your question. You misunderstand RGB, why would 1, 1, 1 be white is 0, 0, 0 is black? You need 255, 255, 255

Comment: @roganjosh So when we should use it. What is the concern to make these functions as they both are creating almost black image

Comment: @meissner_ So when we should use it. What is the concern to make these functions as they both are creating almost black image

Comment: np.zeros and np.ones are used for initializing mathematical structures, not drawing images.

Comment: @HuzaifSayyed because numpy arrays are not solely to do with the colours of images? Just because it doesn't fit your context very well, doesn't mean it can't have any number of uses in any other context.

Comment: So lets leave bgr image. What about binary image

Comment: @HuzaifSayyed in that case, you have your answer from markuscosinus

Answer (score 7):

Initialize your array as `float` data type. Only then 0 will mean black and 1 will mean white:

```
img = np.ones((512,512,3), np.float)
```

**Explanation**:
When `imshow` receives an array of ints, it will assume, that 0 is the minimum and 255 the maximum value, representing black and white in a greyscale image. However if it receives an array of floats it sets these values to 0.0 and 1.0, because it assumes a scaled input.

Answer (score 3):

You need to scale by the number of bits you have in a pixel.  For example,

```
img = 255*np.ones((512, 512, 3), uint8)
```

will produce a white image for 8-bit pixels.

Comment: This is a round-about way, just use [`numpy.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full) and set the fill value as 255